# Position Bootstrap Carousel Image In Center of the Carousel

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, carousel

I have been playing with the Bootstrap Carousel recently. I have undercome a problem of wanting the image to stay responsive and not take the full width of the section that I have it placed inside, but I do want the image itself to keep its aspect ratio which I have done via CSS. I just cannot seem to find how to get the image directly in the center of the div.

Here is my CSS

```
.carousel-image {
display: block;
max-width:460px;
max-height:190px;
width: auto;
height: auto;
```

}

And here is the HTML

```
<div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="carousel-item active">
        <img class="carousel-image" src="images/placeholder.png" alt="First slide">
        <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
            <h3 class="text-success">...</h3>
            <p class="text-success">...</p>
        </div>
   </div>
```

I am using the Bootstrap CDN and the section can be seen live by clicking [here!](http://adonnelly759.students.eeecs.qub.ac.uk/mii/)

Thank you all,
have a wonderful day.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I've made a JS fiddle for you, click **[here](https://jsfiddle.net/et0n3kbp/)** to view it

What I did was select the .carousel-item and added text-align center property

```
.carousel-item {
  text-align: center
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this to center the image.

```
.carousel-image {
  margin:0 auto;
  max-width:460px;
}
```

Comment: I checked this out on the JS fiddle and it does not seem to work.